# Any insights on this Microsoft C 5.1 floating point and DOSBox weirdness?

Tags: c, floating-point, x86-16, dosbox, 16-bit

This is a fantastically strange bug that has been tweaking my noodle for the better part of a day; it took me some time to boil it down to this.

The setup:

- Microsoft C 5.10 (~1988)
- DOSBox 0.74
- Windows 10 (64-bit)

The code (`double.c`):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int, char *[]);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i;
    double n;

    if (argc > 1) {
        puts(argv[1]);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 9999; i++) {
        n = 0.0;
        if (n != 0.0) {
            puts("ERROR1!");
            return -1;
        }
        if (n != 0.0) {
            puts("ERROR2!");
            return -2;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The repro:

1. Compile with MSC 5.1 with no switches (`cl double.c`)
2. Run double.exe
3. Click to activate another application window (away from DOSBox)
4. Click back to DOSBox
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until error occurs

The screenshot:

[image: DOSBox memory corruption MSC 5.1 floating point]

The notes:

I've looked at the assembler and there's nothing strange about it. The `cl /help` shows that it defaults to `/FPi` or *inline with emulator* for handling floating point. I've changed this to `/FPc` (*calls with emulator*) with some success but an error still happens and usually it's ERROR1.

Another bizarre thing: after it happens once or twice, it won't happen again until I recompile the executable!

And finally, I tried this in DOSBox 0.74 on Linux Mint running on a 32-bit ATOM processor and *did not* repro the problem.

I have no illusions about solving this but it's a real brain teaser and seeing as I couldn't find any information on my random, grasping internet searches, I thought I'd better leave this question for posterity.

By popular demand, here's the assembly generated by the `/Fa` switch:

```
;    Static Name Aliases
;
    TITLE   double.c
    NAME    double

    .8087
_TEXT    SEGMENT  WORD PUBLIC 'CODE'
_TEXT    ENDS
_DATA    SEGMENT  WORD PUBLIC 'DATA'
_DATA    ENDS
CONST    SEGMENT  WORD PUBLIC 'CONST'
CONST    ENDS
_BSS    SEGMENT  WORD PUBLIC 'BSS'
_BSS    ENDS
DGROUP    GROUP    CONST, _BSS, _DATA
    ASSUME  CS: _TEXT, DS: DGROUP, SS: DGROUP
EXTRN    __acrtused:ABS
EXTRN    _puts:NEAR
EXTRN    __chkstk:NEAR
EXTRN    __fltused:NEAR
_DATA      SEGMENT
$SG167    DB    'ERROR1!',  00H
$SG169    DB    'ERROR2!',  00H
_DATA      ENDS
CONST      SEGMENT
$T20001    DQ    0000000000r    ;    .0000000000000000
CONST      ENDS
_TEXT      SEGMENT
    ASSUME    CS: _TEXT
; Line 6
    PUBLIC    _main
_main    PROC NEAR
    push    bp
    mov    bp,sp
    mov    ax,12
    call    __chkstk
;    argc = 4
;    argv = 6
;    i = -2
;    n = -10
; Line 10
    cmp    WORD PTR [bp+4],1    ;argc
    jle    $I162
; Line 11
    mov    bx,WORD PTR [bp+6]    ;argv
    push    WORD PTR [bx+2]
    call    _puts
    add    sp,2
; Line 12
; Line 14
$I162:
    mov    WORD PTR [bp-2],0    ;i
    jmp    SHORT $F163
$FC164:
    inc    WORD PTR [bp-2]    ;i
$F163:
    cmp    WORD PTR [bp-2],9999    ;i
    jge    $FB165
; Line 15
    fldz    
    fst    QWORD PTR [bp-10]    ;n
; Line 16
    fcom    QWORD PTR $T20001
    fstp    ST(0)
    fstsw    WORD PTR [bp-12]
    fwait    
    mov    ah,BYTE PTR [bp-11]
    sahf    
    je    $FC164
; Line 21
    mov    ax,OFFSET DGROUP:$SG169
    push    ax
    call    _puts
    add    sp,2
; Line 22
    mov    ax,-2
    mov    sp,bp
    pop    bp
    ret    
$FB165:
; Line 26
    sub    ax,ax
    mov    sp,bp
    pop    bp
    ret    

_main    ENDP
_TEXT    ENDS
END
```

Cheers!

Comment: Can you make the error occur more frequently if you increase the loop iterations from `9999`?

Comment: probably an emulator issue. You know that comparing floats like this is _bad_ right?

Comment: That is beautifully strange. Mind posting the disassembly of the executable?

Comment: We can only speculate about what might be wrong.  I don't see any inherent problem in the program itself (not even in the FP equality comparisons).  I'm inclined to suspect DOSBox, or at least the combination of this version of DOSBox with Windows 10.  v0.74 is 6.5 years old, and Windows 10 was not even a gleam in Bill Gates's eye when DB 0.74 was released.

Comment: There have been a number of problems over the years with DOSBox and floating point. It wouldn't surprise me if this happened. Probably some problem between translating the host SSE instructions to equivalent FPU.

Comment: I'm guessing it's something along the lines of the emulator's floating point state being such that the register it's using for `n` is *close enough* to 0.0 when it task switches back to run your program.  When your instruction to set the value to 0.0 runs, the emulator doesn't bother to do so since it's already 0 (within its tolerance).  But then your comparison is using a different (0) tolerance, so that values don't match.  As @Jean-FrançoisFabre suggests, using a comparison with a tolerance as opposed to `==` is probably a better course of action.

Comment: "Click to activate another application window (away from DOSBox)": that would imply that maybe floating point registers are not properly handled/saved by DosBOX or the legacy libraries it was built with (and maybe I'm way out in the woods). Well, funny.

Comment: The loop iterations is arbitrary; I can set it to 1 and it still happens. Comparing floats for equality is indeed hazardous. But this is an exact check that succeeds once and then fails a second time; it shows a memory corruption that's occurring at a larger level.

Comment: Various compiles have trouble with code that does not _use_ FP math yet has a `double`. Try doing _something _interesting with `double n`

Comment: Note: should never need to prototype the `main() function

Comment: I had more interesting (3D) things going on with `double` earlier in the day that I stripped slowly away until I came up with this repro code. This ol' compiler was complaining when I used `/W3` and didn't have the prototype for `main()`.

Comment: What is the value of `FLT_EVAL_METHOD`?  Do you have a option to insure it is 0?  (All `double` math done as `double`)

Comment: This compiler predates `FLT_EVAL_METHOD` but floating point literals default to `double` so I assuming that's what it uses for math

Comment: One note is that the "succeeds once and fails second time" is somewhat misleading; from the assembly you can see that the compiler has optimized out the first `if (n != 0.0)` test and kept only the second one.  So there is really just one compare being done after each `fldz`.  Doesn't explain the behavior, of course.

Comment: Almost certainly a DOSBox bug, not MSVC.  Especially given that you couldn't repro on DOSBox under Linux Mint, and that changing window focus is necessary(?) to repro.  And the actual asm is very simple, just comparing a zero against one it just stored.  As @NateEldredge said, the ERROR1 vs. ERROR2 message is just due to optimizing away one of the checks making ERROR1 impossible (or not with the other option).

Comment: Unless somehow another DOS program could leave the FPU in MMX state, which would make `fldz` fail.  Or with the x87 stack full, which would result in NaN instead of 0.0, and NAN != NAN.  But I'd have expected an `finit` in the startup code that calls main, which would fix both problems.  (At least it does on Skylake, when I tested in long mode with `movd mm0, eax` / `finit` (with/without this)/ `fldz` / `fst qword [esp+4]`.